# Detect the protobuf REST api with OWASP ZAP on iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, owasp, zap

I want to test Network Communication with [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project).

I could get the general RESTful command.
But I can't get any [protobuf RESTful](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) result.

I have no idea what happen and how to setup the environment of OWASP ZAP for protobuf.

This is my environment I want to test.

```
My App(Real iPhone Device) <-> OWASP ZAP(Mac) <-> Our Server
```

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is your server seeing the request? Is the ZAP machine seeing the response? (You might need wireshark or some network diagnostics). This FAQ can likely help you: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQmobile